# Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I am doing online aptitude test, which will pick up 2 random questions from database and display them on webpage for answering.

The code below is getting answers from candidate ( Simple demo picks up only 2 random questions).

```
// Build Form   
$nbQuestion = 2;
$form = '<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" >';
$form .= getQuestion("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$nbQuestion);
$form .= '<input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"></form>';

// Save answer
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
    for($i=1;i<=$nbQuestion;$i++){
        saveAnswer($i);
    }
}
function getQuestion($query){
    $question = "";
    $i = 1;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $question .= "<b>Question:-<br></b>".$row->Question." <br><br>";
        $question .= "<input type='hidden' name='q".$i."' value='".$row->QNo."'>";
        $question .= "<input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt1."'></input>$a1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt2."'></input>$b1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt3."'></input>$c1 &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt4."'></input>$d1 <br><br> ";
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
function saveAnswer($nb){
    $qId=$_POST["q".$nb];
    if (is_numeric($qId)) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq` WHERE QNo=".$qId);
        $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $ans = $rows1['Ans'];
        $opt = $_POST["answer".$qId];
        if($ans==$opt)
        {
            $val="ct";
        }
        else
        {
            $val="wg";
        }
        mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qId','$opt','$val')")
        or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

code is throughing error like 
Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htd,.. at line while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

and

Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs.... at line `mysql_free_result($result);`

Comment: Sidenote: `$username` is undefined, least that's what it would be if that is your full code.

Comment: You should really bind params and use PDO or mysqli_* to prevent injection. mysql_* was depreciated 50 years ago ;)

Comment: Also, try quoting all your radios `<input type='radio'` - Plus, you don't need `</input>`

Comment: hi i am getting $username from last page pls dont worry about it,...

Comment: It is because your connection is scoped outside of the `getQuestion()` function. You can A. ) pass the connection into the function or 2.) create a connection inside of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting your first error because you don't have a database connection open within your function.  The second error is a follow up error and is caused by the same problem. In order to solve this you can either pass the connection to your function as a parameter or, create a new connection inside of the function. (As stated in the comments by '[Jay Blanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard)' )

Comment: hi thanx above problem is solved, but i am getting error `Undefined Variables` at  $a, $b, $c and $d.

Comment: Well, where do you define those variables? I don't see it in the posted code. If you provide more information I will try to help.